# Need access to SceneCombiner.h and ScenePrivate.h and other headers in the "assimp/code" folder

Tags: build, include, assimp

I've compiled assimp, but i those two .h aren't included in the build output directory and it would be very useful if i could use them.

Is there any way i can access those headers without copy and pasting manually into the build directory? What's the point of the code folder if it isn't possible to include them after the build?

Thanks.